# XSLT 1.0 - how to convert string to TIME format?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

In my incoming XML I get an input string like -

```
50000000
```

I want to convert it using an XSLT into the following format -

```
50:00:00.00
```

How can I achieve it using XSLT? I do not know of any inbuilt functions/templates that can convert it into this format.

Comment: An example does not make a rule. Will the string always have 8 characters - including leading zeros, if required?

Comment: Yes it will always have 8 characters. The format is  HH:MM:SS.SS(milliseconds). And they will have zeros - e.g. - 00000010. This would be ten milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your example, as well as for any other string that contains exactly 8 digits:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 3, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 5, 2)"/>
<xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 7, 2)"/>
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. I am completely new to XSLTs, could you recommend a book/resource on XSLTs?

Comment: I am afraid I'm not the right person to ask this question.